# Getting progress of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a long running stored procedure, executed in a thread (via `TADOStoredProc`) to ensure that the application remains responsive.

There are a number of `RAISERROR() WITH NOWAIT` statements in the stored procedure so I can monitor progress while running it in SSMS.

Is there any way that the application can get these messages so that I can give the users some indication of progress?

Comment: Why not insert the logging in a table that a separate process can read / poll?

Comment: Or create an extended event with sp_statement_started and completed.

Comment: Try handling the [Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection.OnInfoMessage](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection.OnInfoMessage) event.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman, that worked. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages (e.g. `PRINT` and `RAISERROR`) may be captured by handling the [ADODB.Connection.InfoMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/infomessage-event-ado?view=sql-server-ver16) event in ADO classic. This is exposed by the [`Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection.OnInfoMessage`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection.OnInfoMessage) event.

Comment: The comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/255311/212016 were helpful as well to get it working